# servletContext.getRealPath("/") not giving desired path with Tomcat 8.0.44 on Windows

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a web application where I need to create a directory and later return that directory path as response to be used for other ajax processing. Now, i have developed the application and tested it on my mac machine which worked like charm but when I deployed it over a windows machine with same tomcat version, the directory path was not as desired.

I figured out that separators were the issue when I try to create directory. This is how I have coded:

```
String resultDir = sc.getRealPath("/");
resultDir = resultDir+"screenshots/travel/demo";
```

Here the resultDir stores screenshots which I need to show over webpage after making ajax call which directory path as parameter.

Now, I changed forward slashes to `File.separator` so resultDir becomes

```
resultDir = resultDir+"screenshots"+File.separator+"travel"+File.separator+"demo"+File.separator;
```

The response from server comes out to be on windows machine as:

```
C:\Users\roger\Documents\tomcat\webapps\myapp\screenshots\travel\demo\
```

But it gives bad url error on console when making ajax call.

It works great on Mac but giving problem on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the path from servlet context try getting it from request as 
`"request.getContextPath()"`